# Map or flatmap that works like Array.prototype.join in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I find the functionality of `Array.prototype.join` very useful because it only applies the join value to the "inner" connections of the elements in the array. Like so:

`['Hey', 'there'].join('-') // Hey-there`

Where `Array.protoype.map` produces a 'leftover' dash in this example:

`['Hey', 'there'].map(value => value + '-') // Hey-there-`

I've been looking for a succinct way to map arrays without converting
them to a string, possibly to a new array, like so:

`// Intended behaviour
['Hey', 'there'].mapJoin('-') // ['Hey', '-', 'there']`

I'm NOT looking for an imperative solution to the problem as I could write that myself and put it in a global import somewhere.
I'm looking for a native way (ES6 is fine) to express it elegantly
so I can write it in all my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Ramda's intersperse](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#intersperse).

> `R.intersperse('n', ['ba', 'a', 'a']); //=> ['ba', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a']`

Though it's [implemented](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.25.0/source/intersperse.js) imperatively.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Now if this were only in the Array.prototype :). Since you provided the term for it, I also found 'intersperse-js' which is just that function.

Answer (score 3):

You could join with a wanted separator, and split by the addition comma (or any other value, if taken for join).

```js
var array = ['Hey', 'there'],
    separator = '-',
    result = array.join(',' + separator + ',').split(',');
    
console.log(result);
```

Another solution could be to take new indices and fill the previos index with the sepparator.

```js
var array = ['Hey', 'there'],
    separator = '-',
    result = Object.assign(
        [],
        ...array.map((v, i) => ({ [i * 2 - 1]: separator, [i * 2]: v }))
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'd really like to avoid converting it to a string, so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: Clever usage of `[-1]:separator`

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly pretty or elegant, but

```
['Hey', 'there'].reduce(
  (acc, value, i, arr) => (acc.push(value), i < arr.length - 1 ? acc.push('-') : 0, acc),
  [],
)
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's native but not very elegant, your right :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version of @[AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)'s answer.

```js
const data = ['Hey', 'there'];

const output = data.reduce((p, c, i, a) => p.concat(i < a.length -1 ? [c, '-'] : [c]), []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```js
const mapJoin = (arr, joiner) => {  
  return arr.reduce( (curr, t) => curr.concat(t, joiner), []).slice(0, arr.length*2-1)
}

const data = ["Hey", "There"]

console.log(mapJoin(data, "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive encoding

```js
const intersperse = (sep, [ x, ...rest ]) =>
  // base case; return empty result
  x === undefined
    ? []
  
  // one remaining x, return singleton
  : rest.length === 0
    ? [ x ]

  // default case; return pair of x and sep and recur
  : [ x, sep ] .concat (intersperse (sep, rest))
  
  
console.log
  ( intersperse ("~", [])              // []
  , intersperse ("~", [ 1 ])           // [ 1 ]
  , intersperse ("~", [ 1, 2 ])        // [ 1, ~, 2 ]
  , intersperse ("~", [ 1, 2, 3 ])     // [ 1, ~, 2, ~, 3 ]
  , intersperse ("~", [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])  // [ 1, ~, 2, ~, 3, ~, 4 ]
  )
```

Comment: Nice answer, like always. However, `x === undefined` is probably not the best way to test if the array is empty because it wouldn't work for sparse arrays like `[undefined, 1, 2, 3]`. Might I suggest that you define it as `const intersperse = (sep, xs) => xs.length < 2 ? xs.slice() : xs.slice(0, 1).concat(sep, intersperse(sep, xs.slice(1)));`?

Comment: Oh, even better: `const intersperse = (sep, xxs) => xxs.length < 2 ? xxs.slice() : (([x, ...xs] = xxs) => [x, sep].concat(intersperse(sep, xs)))()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) function, which is easy to define:

```js
const intersperse = (x, ys) => [].concat(...ys.map(y => [x, y])).slice(1);

console.log(intersperse("-", ["Hey", "there"])); // ["Hey", "-", "there"]
console.log(intersperse(0, [1, 2, 3]));          // [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
console.log(intersperse(0, []));                 // []
```

Alternatively, you could decompose it into smaller functions:

```js
const concat = xss => [].concat(...xss);
const concatMap = (f, xs) => concat(xs.map(f));
const intersperse = (x, ys) => concatMap(y => [x, y], ys).slice(1);

console.log(intersperse("-", ["Hey", "there"])); // ["Hey", "-", "there"]
console.log(intersperse(0, [1, 2, 3]));          // [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
console.log(intersperse(0, []));                 // []
```

You can even install them on `Array.prototype`:

```js
Object.assign(Array.prototype, {
    concatenate() {
        return [].concat(...this);
    },
    concatMap(f) {
        return this.map(f).concatenate();
    },
    intersperse(x) {
        return this.concatMap(y => [x, y]).slice(1);
    }
});

console.log(["Hey", "there"].intersperse("-")); // ["Hey", "-", "there"]
console.log([1, 2, 3].intersperse(0));          // [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
console.log([].intersperse(0));                 // []
```

In Haskell, you'd write this as follows:

```hs
intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse x = drop 1 . concatMap (\y -> [x, y])
```

Can you see the similarities?